I'm looking for a horror movie about a haunted house
I have no idea what the movie's name is. I just remember a few scenes, and the name of a character. It was probably a low budget movie, color and probably came out in 1999-2009 Some details:

One of characters name is Liz
The starting scene has all the teenagers sitting around a campfire 
At the end, Liz almost escapes but is electrocuted outside
This is pretty vague, but one of the guys head gets cut off 
Group of horny teenagers
There's one scene where a couple is having sex, and a mirror falls on top of them, killing them 


Welcome to the community. You may have more helpful information than you realize. If you know, please also describe when you saw it, in what language, country and year of production, plot locale, names of actors, color or BW, etc. I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

Killer Instinct (2001)
You can read more about the movie here:
http://horror-movie-a-day.blogspot.hu/2012/06/killer-instinct.html
One of the characters is Liz, there is a scene in the movie where the falling glass kills someone lying on a bed, and there is someone who is decapitated. 

"It’s textbook stuff for a while, but there’s a great falling glass
  kill and a funny rolling head gag, and it takes the unusual step of
  killing the four guys first before focusing on the girls."

Here is part of the scene with the death by falling glass:



